# Selection screen is not executed

Tags: report, abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm getting no errors when I activate my abap program but when I try to execute this nothing happens. I previously tried it and it worked. This fragment of code for example was ok before but now it doesn't do anything.

```
    REPORT  Z_xx
    DATA: lv_response1 TYPE flag,
    lv_response2 TYPE flag,
    lv_response3 TYPE flag.

    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 100.
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK B1 WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-t01.

    PARAMETERS: s1 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1,
        s2 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1,
        s3 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1,
        s4 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.

    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK B1.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 100.
```

Comment: There are no active commands in it, just declarations. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Didn't know I have to call screen. Previously I didn't use begin of screen. All ok now.

Comment: Sorry for the delete. I thought it shouldn't stay on the site because it was a little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you defined your radiogroup inside screen 100, and you are executing (implicitly) [standard selection screen](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abenstandard_selscreen_glosry.htm) 1000 which is empty. 
To use your parameters call your screen 100 like this

```
CALL SELECTION-SCREEN 100.
```

Read more about selection screens [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/4a/43c0475a503f04e10000000a421937/content.htm?frameset=/en/4a/43c16a5a503f04e10000000a421937/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/d5/01fb7d1d574978836b09417434af98/plain.htm&node_id=60&show_children=false) to produce functional code.